# I need a way to access media element properties from another thread

Tags: c#, position, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement built into a GUI using visual studios, but in the backend code I need to access the Position property in the video it loads in order to use the time in some calculations.  I'm getting an error saying I can't access it because another thread owns it.

I've tried using the GetProperty() GetValue() methods, and I've also approached it with an invoker but can't find a method in MediaElement to get the position.

Is there an easy way to access properties of an object in another thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't post the error but I'm guessing it's telling you that you can't just access objects on the UI thread from other/non-UI threads, in WPF you typically need the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to [invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) into another thread. more info and samples [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher).

Comment: Ah, I see, yes this works well.  I'm also going to need to use it on the canvas over the media element.  Seems a bit messy, but it'll do. Thanks!

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211016/c-wpf-automatically-call-dispatcher-invoke-when-needed) a really nice post on the Dispatcher as well!